# laravel livewire image form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have form submit function which is working just fine in normal controller but since I've moved my function to livewire component it returns error

## Error

```
ErrorException
Undefined index: attachment
```

## Code

> Error line commented

```
$chat = new BidChat;
// other fields
if ($this->attachment) {
    $attachment = $this->attachment;
    $filename = 'chat-attachment' . '-' . time() . '.' . $attachment->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);


    $valid_images = ['image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png'];
    if(in_array($_FILES['attachment']['type'], $valid_images)){ <-- error comes from this line
        Image::make($attachment)->resize(1300, 362)->save($location);
    }

    $chat->attachment = $filename;
}
$chat->save();
```

## Debug

Result of `dd($this->attachment);`

```
Livewire\TemporaryUploadedFile {#1559 ▼
  +"disk": "local"
  #storage: Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemAdapter {#1538 ▶}
  #path: "livewire-tmp/najcwwb2OMw5wq0khtJp5hvkFfWk36-metaYmlkLWF0dGFjaG1lbnQtMTUzODEwMDQ0MS5wbmc=-.png"
  -test: false
  -originalName: "najcwwb2OMw5wq0khtJp5hvkFfWk36-metaYmlkLWF0dGFjaG1lbnQtMTUzODEwMDQ0MS5wbmc=-.png"
  -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Temp"
  filename: "najcwwb2OMw5wq0khtJp5hvkFfWk36-metaYmlkLWF0dGFjaG1lbnQtMTUzODEwMDQ0MS5wbmc=-.png"
  basename: "phpBAD0.tmp"
  pathname: "C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\Temp\phpBAD0.tmp"
  extension: "tmp"
  realPath: "C:\laragon\www\mysite\storage\app\livewire-tmp/najcwwb2OMw5wq0khtJp5hvkFfWk36-metaYmlkLWF0dGFjaG1lbnQtMTUzODEwMDQ0MS5wbmc=-.png"
  size: 15036
  writable: false
  readable: false
  executable: false
  file: false
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

## HTML

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="submit" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  @csrf
  <input type="file" wire:model="attachment" class="form-control" />

  <button class="button btn-block">Save</button>
</form>
```

**Any idea?**

#### Update

[It seems to be known issue](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/1106)

Comment: you need to change your upload file code like this https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/file-uploads

Comment: @KamleshPaul i think you misunderstood me, my problem is not uploading but to validate selected file `type` I need to get the type of file `'image/jpeg','image/gif','image/png'` if my file is any of those then i resize it. but if is different type `i.e. zip` i don't run resizing function

Answer (score 0):

in livewire you can't `$_FILES['attachment']['type']` access this data for validation you can do like this

```php
$chat = new BidChat;
// other fields
if ($this->attachment) {
    $attachment = $this->attachment;
    $filename = 'chat-attachment' . '-' . time() . '.' . $attachment->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);

    $this->validate([
        'attachment' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif',
    ]);

    Image::make($attachment)->resize(1300, 362)->save($location);
    $chat->attachment = $filename;
}
$chat->save();
```

ref link https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/file-uploads

Comment: Thanks but I think that would be wrong I guess, as I mentioned in my previous comment the file is not limited to images it can be other types such as zip or PDF etc. I only need `Image::make` if it's image if it's zip, PDF etc. I do not need to use `Image::make`

Comment: ` $this->validate()` wlll  throw error if type is not match so it won't react `Image::make($` this line

Comment: Exactly, I don't want it to return error. I want allow all files rar, zip, PDF, docs, doc, xlxs jpg, png, gif to be upload, **just if it's image resize it.**

Comment: That was the idea why I separated image validation from general laravel validation and created `$valid_images`